# Get ID by the group and then count unique value for these IDs

Tags: r

I have a data frame `df` as below:

```
Name = c("Tom D Frost","Tom D Frost", "Tom D Frost", "William J Hardy", "William J Hardy", "Steven D Debauche", "Nicholas K Foster", "Sean F Williamson")
Institute = c("ASA", "ASA", "ASA", "BSC", "BSC", "BSC", "AXB", "PSDZ")
ID = c(165, 170, 189, 181, 165, 784, 165, 170)
df = data.frame(Name, Institute, ID)

#df
            Name       Institute  ID
1        Tom D Frost       ASA    165
2        Tom D Frost       ASA    170
3        Tom D Frost       ASA    189
4    William J Hardy       BSC    181
5    William J Hardy       BSC    165
6  Steven D Debauche       BSC    784
7  Nicholas K Foster       AXB    165
8  Sean F Williamson      PSDZ    170
```

For each Name, I would like to get a group of ID and then count unique Name for those group of ID. For this sample df, I am expecting a result like this:

```
Name             Institute    UniqueCountofNamebyIDGroup
Tom D Frost        ASA            4
William J Hardy    BSC            3
Steven D Debauche  BSC            1
Nicholas K Foster  AXB            3
Sean F Williamson  PSDZ           2
```

In the data frame, I would like to count Names for group of IDs. For example, "Tom D Frost" has 3 ID such as 165, 170, and 189. So, I would like to count the unique names for those IDs. So, 165, 170 and 189 has 4 unique names such as "Tom D Frost", "William J Hardy", "Nicholas K Foster" and "Sean F Williamson". Therefore, unique count will be 4 for "Tom D Frost"

I tried using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
group_by(Name) %>%
summarise(uniqueCount = n())
```

This just gives me frequency for each Name as below:

```
           Name                      UniqueCount
         <fctr>                      <int>
1     Nicholas K Foster                1
2     Sean F Williamson                1
3     Steven D Debauche                1
4       Tom D Frost                    3
5     William J Hardy                  2
```

As mentioned above, I would like to count unique Name for group of IDs that belong to each Name in `df` not their frequency.

Any help and support is greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: From this data, Tom D Frost should have 3 (not 4) as IDcount and Sean F Williamson should have only 1 (not 2).

Comment: Either `count(df, Name, Institute)` or `df %>% group_by(Name, Institute) %>% summarise(n_distinct(ID))` (not sure as your description of the problem is ultra confusing).

Comment: @RonakShah It is not duplicate of that question. I added more information to the problem.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I added more information to the question. Sorry that it sounded confusing earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a self-join:

```
df %>%
  inner_join(df, by="ID") %>% 
  group_by(Name.x, Institute.x) %>% 
  summarise(UniqueCount = n_distinct(Name.y, Institute.y))

# Source: local data frame [5 x 3]
# Groups: Name.x [?]
# 
#              Name.x Institute.x UniqueCount
#              <fctr>      <fctr>       <int>
# 1 Nicholas K Foster         AXB           3
# 2 Sean F Williamson        PSDZ           2
# 3 Steven D Debauche         BSC           1
# 4       Tom D Frost         ASA           4
# 5   William J Hardy         BSC           3
```